# Forge JS Library - How to define RSA publicKey?

Tags: javascript, cryptography, rsa

I am using the [Forge Github Library](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge) to deal with cryptography.

I have a client with a server (node.js with the same library) socket communication ([socket.io](http://socket.io/)). In the client side I use the forge to generate a RSA public/private key and send the publicKey to the server. But when I receive the key in the server, I do not receive the `encrypt` method in the object. 
This is the object that I receive: `Object {n: BigInteger, e: BigInteger}`. So how can I create a RSA public key with this informations to encrypt a message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert the public key object to an exportable format, for example PEM, which is binary encoded as base64. Send the PEM content to server and recreate the public key

```
 // convert a Forge public key to PEM-format
var pem = pki.publicKeyToPem(publicKey);

// convert a PEM-formatted public key to a Forge public key
var publicKey = pki.publicKeyFromPem(pem);
```

It would be also possible to build the public key from modulus and exponent (n,e), but I do not know if forge allows it